# Check if site exists from client side

Tags: development, client-object-model

I am currently running the following code to check if there is a site with a title equal to my string `myname`.

This code is however very time consuming because I have a large number of sites. Is there a more efficient method to test this, without using `SPWeb.Exists` because I am working Client Side.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(spUri))
{
   context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
   Web web = context.Web;
   context.Load(web, w => w.Title, w => w.Webs);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   int j = 0;

   do
   {
       if (web.Webs[j].Title == myname) exists = true;
       j++;
   } while (!exists || j++ != web.Webs.Count);
}
```

Comment: Is finding your subsite by title a requirement? Can't you use the site URL ?

Comment: Site URL would be an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use linq query:

```
    var subWeb = (from w in web.Webs where w.Title == YourTitle select w).SingleOrDefault();
    if (subWeb != null)
    {
      // if found true
      return true;
    }
```

See more at: http://www.daniellewis.me.uk/2013/10/02/a-quick-way-to-check-if-a-sub-site-exists-using-the-sharepoint-2013-net-client-side-object-model-csom/#sthash.z7ebixoz.dpuf

Comment: I think the expensive call is the actual query to get the webs list

Comment: You are right. He needs a way to perform it in CSOM and not server side. So he can use the sample I provided and compare it with the one he already has to see if there is any performance gain.

Comment: Huge performance gain. Thanks a million for this!
@MdMazzotti The expensive call is the do - while loop. If it's the last match has 200k iterations. Linq is much more efficient.

Comment: @MartijnBurger thanks for the info! It can come in handy

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to check if the specified URL exists.
Example:

```
using(var client = new WebClient()) {       
    try{
        string check = client.DownloadString("http://siteroot/urlSubSiteUrl");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){    
       //if you get here the site doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Source and more info: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid?lq=1)